# Вычислить переменную и передать в функцию

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть функция, которая "делает" слайдер. (www.teplydom-orel.ru)

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#acc_slider").zAccordion({
    tabWidth: 80,
    speed: 600,
    auto: false,
    startingSlide: 0,
    trigger: "mouseover",
    pause: true,
    slideClass: 'slider',
    animationStart: function () {
        $('#slider').find('li.slider-open div').css('display', 'none');
        $('#slider').find('li.slider-previous div').css('display', 'none');
    },
    animationComplete: function () {
        $('#slider').find('li div').fadeIn(600);
    },
    width: 1170,
    height: 380
    });
  });
</script>
```

Логика такова, что при переходе на страницу слайдер начинает крутить все сначала, а нужно чтоб начинал с той вкладки, на которую перешли. Щелкнули на "входные двери" и на этой странице слайдер имеет открытую вкладку "входные двери".

Отвечает за это все startingSlide: 0, соответственно его нужно проставить в зависимости от страницы.

Имеем архив

```
var arr = ["pag1", "pag2", "pag3"];
```

где pag1 - уникальный ID страницы, который передается в функцию

Нужно найти ключ для pag1 прибавить к нему 1 и проставить в startingSlide

```
startingSlide: ключ(pag1) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант к ссылке на страницу добавить #1, а после загрузке страницы брать то что после хэша с помощью window.loaction.hash и вставлять эту данную в startingSlide,